# java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address)

Tags: java, sockets, networking

When the following code is run, I get an exception thrown in the line `socket = new DatagramSocket(8079, ip);` saying java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address). I am not sure why this is happening. Here is the code:

```
public Memcached(String target, int serverPort, int attackDuration) throws MalformedURLException {
        targetURL = new URL("http://" + target);
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.attackDuration = attackDuration * 1000;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getByName(targetURL.toExternalForm().replace("http://", ""));
            Log.d("tag1", ip.toString());
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.out.println("Unknown host");
            ipAddressAbleToBeFound = false;
        }
        if (ipAddressAbleToBeFound) {
            try {
                socket = new DatagramSocket(8079, ip);
            }
            catch(SocketException se) {
                System.out.println("Unable to send request, is it down already??");
                se.printStackTrace();
                socketAbleToBeCreated = false;
            }
            if (socketAbleToBeCreated) {
                while(System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + attackDuration) {
                    byte[] buffer = {10,23,12,31,43,32,24};

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, ip, 8079);
                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                    }
                    catch(IOException ioe) {
                        System.out.println("I/O error occurred");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got around this by doing `socket = new DatagramSocket();` as opposed to `socket = new DatagramSocket(8079, ip);`. It looks like you don't need to specify port and InetAddress in the DatagramSocket, you just need to do so in the DatagramPacket.

Comment: I did this. although there was no error, I was still unable to send data to my esp32 with the right IP address and port stated in DatagramPacket.